# XMLHttp Request and Blobs

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, blob

I'm working on an app and I would like to implement some blobs in it so i can do web workers on the fly without having to create another file manually. here is my code. I can't figure out why it won't work.

```
var blob = new Blob(["onmessage = function(e){ var request = new XMLHttpRequest() \
request.onload=function(e){ console.log(e) } \
request.open('GET', 'text.txt') \
request.send(); }"]);
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

It returns an error somewhere between request.onload and request.send. Anybody have any idea why?

Comment: There’s no type in your blob. It should be `var blob = new Blob([`…`], {type: "application/javascript"})`.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't affect it. It works without the type of blob for what I am doing anyway. I can output a string to console without the type.

Comment: I know, this isn’t the only mistake. It’s just the first thing I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a syntax error in your blob code. Everytime you write this:

```
statement1 \
statement2
```

it is being parsed as this:

```
statement1 statement2
```

The lack of a semicolon is the reason for the syntax error (*“`SyntaxError`: missing `;` before statement”*).

You should put semicolons inbetween the statements and optionally use `\n\` instead of only `\`.

Then, you should also include the type for the blob.

This should work:

```
var blob = new Blob(["onmessage = function(e){\n\
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();\n\
    request.onload = function(e){\n\
      console.log(e);\n\
    };\n\
    request.open('GET', 'text.txt');\n\
    request.send();\n\
  };"], {
    type: "application/javascript"
  });
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Alternatively, use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which natively support multi-line text.

Comment: thank you.  I think the root of my problem was not having the "\n\" in my code.